# pandas DataFrame - calculate average for a column for each unique index without hardcoding each index label?

Tags: python, pandas

Really liking pandas so far, here is something I can't solve though!

I'm showing a simplified dataframe here for some flight data. Carriers are the carriers like Am. Air. and Uni. Air.

```
print (df)

Carrier | Num_Passengers
AA        40
AA        35
AA        64
UA        40
UA        25
UA        56
```

In my dataframe, carrier is the lefthand side vertical index, and number of passengers is my index on the top for the column.

I have identified each unique index by the following:

```
carriers = df.index.unique()
```

which gives me

```
array(['AA','UA'], dtype=object)
```

I would then like to calculate the mean Num_Passengers for each of those unique indices (AA and UA) without explicitly saying so. Some pseudo code since I'm not sure how I'd do it:

```
for "carrier" in carriers:
    make a new dataframe or array containing only the passengers 
    for "carrier" and calculate the average
```

I've really been struggling with this one and googled up and down the internet. Maybe my phrasing is wrong but theres gotta be an answer out there somewhere!

Comment: I think you want `groupby`.  Look it up in the pandas documentation.

Comment: @BrenBarn very speedy answer. I've never used groupby but I've seen it before. I'll look into it now thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking to groupby your index and then get the mean number of passengers.

```
df.groupby(level=0).mean()

             Num_Passengers
Carrier                
AA            46.333333
UA            40.333333
```

Comment: This works much better than the for loop I just wrote. Pandas is amazing and thank you for knowing this!!